# Option of different size in a select

Tags: html, css, html-select

I am trying to do a dropdown with different size because my options are in different groups.

I can change the color of the text, the color of the background, but not the height of the option neither the font-size (I mean, I can change it but not have 2 separate ones)

the code

```
<select>
    <option class="title" disabled>Title 1</option>
    <option>Select 1</option>
    <option>Select 2</option>
    <option class="title" disabled>Title 2</option>
    <option>Select 3</option>
 </select>
```

the CSS

```
select .title
{
    color:#E0E0E0;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:15px;
    background-color:#0000FF;
}

select option
{
    color:#0000FF;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:normal;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#0000FF;
}
```

Comment: Yes you can, but `select option` counts for any option items and overwrites `select .title`. Try to flip the both CSS selectors.

Comment: yes, I tried to flip them with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware of a element called `<optgroup>` specially for something like this?

```
<select>
     <optgroup label="Title 1">
       <option>Select 1</option>
       <option>Select 2</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Title 2">
        <option>Select 3</option>
     </optgroup>
</select>
```

And if you want to change the `optgroup` textsize try this

```
optgroup:before {
    content: "Demo";
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

[**Change Size Of OPTGROUP Header Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fEdkj/)

Comment: thanks, now I need to find how to style them and that will be perfect

Comment: See my answer below. Font-size also won't work for optgroups.

Comment: @Memes why don't you go for jQuery? because you won't get too many options for customizing options

Comment: Well if he really must have this font size that might work, but including an entire js library for a simple styling issue is far from best practice.

Comment: thanks guys, I did it, maybe not clean but that works. I post an answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, styles are quite limited on a lot of form elements. The `<option>` tag can have some changed styles, but font-size isn't one of them. It also depends on the browser you're using.

See this page for an overview of what is possible:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it

the HTML

```
<select>
 <optgroup label="Title 1"></optgroup> 

  <option>Select 1</option>
  <option>Select 2</option>

   <optgroup label="Title 2"></optgroup>

   <option>Select 3</option>
 </select>
```

the CSS

```
select
{
 width: 100%;
 font-size:24px;
}
select optgroup 
{
 color:#E0E0E0;
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color:#0000FF;
}
select option
{
 color:#0000FF;
 font-weight:normal;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

the height though is not working.

Comment: do you want a dirty way than go for this, cross browser is not 100% sure http://jsfiddle.net/fEdkj/

Comment: your solution does not work under Chrome at least in your jsfiddle

Comment: that's what I told you, it's not 100% cross-browser stuff ;)

Comment: mine neither actually OK in chrome and FF, not OK in IE9 and Opera. see it there : http://jsfiddle.net/fEdkj/3/

Comment: our solution are super dirty haha